How to use correctly when_value_edited whit npyscreen
I'm new using npyscreen. I am creating a terminal gui with three boxes, one that contains all, and the other two insid, one of the left and the other to the right side. The left one contains a list of options and the second will show the content of each option.
My desire behavior is when just press enter over any option the content of the right box will update. The same behavior when use the mouse. But when the script starts and press the down arrow key the content box is updated. I dont know what Im doing wrong.
Here my code:
#! /usr/bin/python3

import npyscreen


class ProgramOptions(npyscreen.BoxTitle):
    def __init__(self, *args, **keywords):
        super(ProgramOptions, self).__init__(*args, **keywords)

        self.entry_widget.when_cursor_moved = self.h_select_option
        # self.entry_widget.when_value_edited = self.h_select_option
        self.entry_widget.mouse_event = self.h_mouse_event

    def h_select_option(self):
        selected = self.entry_widget.values[self.entry_widget.cursor_line]
        self.parent.update_content(selected)

    def h_mouse_event(self):
        selected = self.entry_widget.values[self.entry_widget.cursor_line]
        self.parent.update_content(selected)


class ContentOption(npyscreen.BoxTitle):
    _contained_widget = npyscreen.MultiLine


class MainForm(npyscreen.Form):

    def create(self):

        self.check_cursor_move = False

        y, x = self.useable_space()
        self.options = self.add(ProgramOptions,
                                name="Options",
                                max_width=x // 6,
                                relx=2,
                                rely=2,
                                )
        self.options.entry_widget.values = [
            'Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Option 4']

        self.content = self.add(ContentOption,
                                name="Content",
                                relx=(x // 6) + 4,
                                rely=2
                                )

    def update_content(self, option):
        # Actualiza el contenido basado en la opción seleccionada
        content = f"You selected: {option}\n\nThis is the content for {option}."
        self.content.entry_widget.values = content.split('\n')
        self.content.display()
        # self.display()

    def afterEditing(self):
        self.parentApp.setNextForm(None)


class TestApp(npyscreen.NPSAppManaged):
    def onStart(self):
        self.addForm("MAIN", MainForm, name="ROBOT CONFIGURATION")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TestApp().run()


enter image description here
I would like get the correct behavior and know how to use correctly the methods handlers.
